# Taking the record with the max date

Tags: oracle, date, max, analytic-functions

Let's assume I extract some set of data.

i.e.

```
SELECT A, date
FROM table
```

I want just the record with the max date (for each value of A). I could write

```
SELECT A, col_date
  FROM TABLENAME t_ext
 WHERE col_date = (SELECT MAX (col_date)
                     FROM TABLENAME t_in
                    WHERE t_in.A = t_ext.A)
```

**But my query is really long... is there a more compact way using ANALYTIC FUNCTION to do the same?**

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The analytic function approach would look something like

```
SELECT a, some_date_column
  FROM (SELECT a,
               some_date_column,
               rank() over (partition by a order by some_date_column desc) rnk
          FROM tablename)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Note that depending on how you want to handle ties (or whether ties are possible in your data model), you may want to use either the `ROW_NUMBER` or the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function rather than `RANK`.

Comment: @Gik25 - A tie would occur if there were, say, two rows in `TABLENAME` that had the same value for `A` and the same value for `SOME_DATE_COLUMN`.  Your original query would return both of those rows as would mine.  If, on the other hand, you used the `ROW_NUMBER` function, only one of the two rows would be returned (though the choice of which row to return would be arbitrary).

Answer (score 25):

If `date` and `col_date` are the same columns you should simply do:

```
SELECT A, MAX(date) FROM t GROUP BY A
```

Why not use:

```
WITH x AS ( SELECT A, MAX(col_date) m FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY A )
SELECT t.A, t.date FROM TABLENAME t JOIN x ON x.A = t.A AND x.m = t.col_date
```

Otherwise:

```
SELECT A, FIRST_VALUE(date) KEEP(dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY col_date DESC)
  FROM TABLENAME
 GROUP BY A
```

Comment: @Matt: Yes, but only if the OP wants just these 2 columns and not the whole row (as it is implied in the question).

Comment: @ypercube I agree, and that is what the question looks like

Comment: I've couln't make third query work in my Oracle 11g. And second query is missing a **group by** clause. It should be: `WITH x AS ( SELECT A, MAX(col_date) m FROM TABLENAME **group by A**)
SELECT A, date FROM TABLENAME t JOIN x ON x.A = t.A AND x.m = t.col_date`

Answer (score 10):

You could also use:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM 
        TABLENAME t
    JOIN
        ( SELECT A, MAX(col_date) AS col_date
          FROM TABLENAME
          GROUP BY A
        ) m
      ON  m.A = t.A
      AND m.col_date = t.col_date
```

Comment: This would be a good choice if there was an index on `(a, col_date)`, especially if there are lots of dates for each distinct value of A.

Answer (score 4):

A is the key, max(date) is the value, we might simplify the query as below:

```
SELECT distinct A, max(date) over (partition by A)
  FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Justin Cave answer is the best, but if you want antoher option, try this:

```
select A,col_date
from (select A,col_date
    from tablename 
      order by col_date desc)
      where rownum<2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Oracle 12C, you can fetch a specific number of rows with `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`.
In your case this implies an `ORDER BY`, so the performance should be considered.

```sql
SELECT A, col_date
FROM TABLENAME t_ext
ORDER BY col_date DESC NULLS LAST
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

The `NULLS LAST` is just in case you may have null values in your field.

Answer (score -6):

```
SELECT mu_file, mudate
  FROM flightdata t_ext
 WHERE mudate = (SELECT MAX (mudate)
                     FROM flightdata where mudate < sysdate)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it matches the question?