# Pagination using an array in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Actually, I need to do pagination.

How do I do pagination by using a bunch of array data in CakePHP?

For an urgent fix I have handled my code by using JavaScript pagination. Is it only possible by using the model? Can't we do pagination with array data?

Comment: Doesn't the last stored ID maximum? If yes, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898020/oracle-taking-the-record-with-the-max-date).

Comment: Search is google you will get tons of results....

Comment: Negative voter Please comment why you have given negative vote. Can you please explain

Answer (score 1):

In [Oracle 12c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#History) or later, you can write:

```
select *
from table
order by id desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`select * from YourtableName where rowid in (select max(rowid) from YourtableName)`